# How to make the baseline of inline HTML table and inline CSS table the same?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML:

```html
Some text, and an HTML table
<table style="display:inline-table"><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></table>
and a CSS table
<span style="display:inline-table;border-spacing:2px"><span style="display:table-row"><span style="display:table-cell">1</span><span style="display:table-cell">2</span></span><span style="display:table-row"><span style="display:table-cell">3</span><span style="display:table-cell">4</span></span></span>
```

On Firefox and Chrome, the baselines and spacing of the inline tables differ slightly. How can they be made the same? (In particular, I want the HTML table baseline, not the CSS table one.)

Comment: Why don't you make table like table and try to use css solution?

Comment: I don't think there is a simple solution...

Comment: panther: The specific reason is I want span-style copy-paste behavior of rows (so no spaces when I copy paste.)